# Passing value from one task output to other task

Tags: azure-devops

Unable to find the option to pass value from one task output to other task in Azure deveops pipeline.

Pass value of Id which is an output of task to next task as an input.

[task output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmn1t.png)

Comment: Hi,Ramya Do you try the Output variables section?Is this what you need?If you have any question,please kindly let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this through Output variables part of the task.

1.Use outputs in the same job

In the [Output variables](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/preview/outputvariable.md) section, give the producing task a reference name. Then, in a downstream step, you can use the form `$(<ReferenceName>.<VariableName>)` to refer to output variables.

[image]

2.Use outputs in a different job

You must use YAML to consume output variables in a different job.

For details,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cshell#use-output-variables-from-tasks).